# Check independence using the relative distance test for generating random numbers

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, distance

I generated $500000$ random numbers of uniform distribution $[0,1]$ with $10$ Intervals, and I obtained the table as below. I compute chi-squared test is 3.037 with acceptable with the probability of $0.95$. I would like to   check independence using the relative distance test with the $10$ intervals. However, I have no idea to solve it. Please help me to solve it. Thanks.

[image]

The Relative distance test can be express such as
[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference for the test? It may be known by other names

Comment: I add the expression of RD test, Sorry I have no other reference